# Nest.js serializer like Django

Tags: django, serialization, nestjs

I am currently using Nest.js, Postgresql, Typeorm for my backend. Now I am trying to do is to see an specific entity field differently by each user. 
For example there are 10 posts and one user has bookmarked 3 of them. Only a user who bookmarked the post can get `isBookmarked = true`, others `isBookmarked = false`. 
I used Django a bit and I used serializer to implement the same logic. I looked for Nest.js serializer (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization) but I think it is a bit different than what I thought. Please tell me how to use this serializer as Django does, or any other ways to implement the logic.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. How would the use get `isBookmarked`? Is it part of the response? How does Django actually handle this? Can you give an example?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel  `isBookmarked` for only response. In Django, I made serializer with `isBookMarked` in it, and as a function inside serializer, check the user who requested, and find out the requested user has bookmarked the post. In Summary, user has bookmarked lists on database entity, but not `isBookMarked` in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since NestJS is using `class-transform` you can follow the documentation to achieve what you wants => https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#additional-data-transformation

```js
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export class Post {
  id: number;

  @Transform(({ value }) => isBookmarkedByTheUser())
  bookmarked: boolean;
}
```

Something like that ;)